# How to retrieve all users with their last post

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get my users (authors actually, there will be maximum of 5-6 authors) with their one last post to show in a sidebar in the homepage. Since they will be listed in the homepage I am trying to reduce the amount of sql queries due to performance issues. I have tried;

```
$users=User::with(array('posts'=>function($query){

        $query->take(1);
    }))->get();
```

However it gets only one post in total, not one for every user. And my sql knowledge is limited.

How can I solve my poblem using Eloquent ORM, Query Builder or raw sql query?

Comment: It seems I should get the users first, and then iterate over them to get their last posts. so "number of sql queries = 1 + number of users". Seems ugly :/

Comment: Can you use SQL for your query?  If not, you should remove it as a tag.

Comment: I can. That's why I put it. The question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277115/select-newest-record-group-by-username-in-sql-server-2008 seems close to mine. I am investigating on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to define a `hasOne` relationship on the `User` model ordering by the posts `created_at` column.

```
public function lastPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Post')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Then your query would be as such.

```
$users = User::with('lastPost')->get();
```

To limit the columns you can constrain the query either at the relationship level:

```
return $this->hasOne('Post')->select('id', 'user_id', 'title', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

Or when you use the `with` method:

```
$users = User::with(['lastPost' => function($query)
{
    $query->select('id', 'user_id', 'title', 'created_at');
})->get();
```

Note that you need the **user_id** and **created_at** columns as well, as they're required for the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses in the query.

Comment: thx. that works nice and looks beautiful. But I need only title and id columns of the posts. I am very confused about building complex queries. Can you please tell me how to get only specified columns?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated the answer with the extra information.

Comment: Again many thanks. But the result is not completely object. I am reaching the results using $user->lastPost['attributes']['title'] is this ok? I thought I can reach it using $user->lastPost->title

Comment: Once you have a single user object you should be able to do `$user->lastPost->title`, I've tested it here and it works fine for me.

Comment: OH my bad. It works flawlessly. thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The general SQL way to do this is:

```
select p.*
from posts p join
     (select p.authorid, max(created_at) as maxdate
      from posts p
      group by p.authorid
     ) psum
     on p.authorid = psum.authorid and p.created_at = psum.maxdate
```

This assumes that there is are no duplicates.

Depending on the database you are using, there are definitely other ways to write this query.  That version is standard SQL.